# Should ModelMapper instance be reused to take advantage of cached TypeMaps?

Tags: java, modelmapper

I'm using [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org/) to do straight-forward maps between objects.

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
// TypeMap created
mapper.map(sourceObj, destObj);

mapper = new ModelMapper();
// TypeMap is recreated
mapper.map(sourceObj, destObj);
```

I noticed in the source code that if a `TypeMap` doesn't exist between `sourceObj` and `destObj` that it will cache the `TypeMap` in `getOrCreate` method.

As far as I can tell this cache is tied to the mapper instance, meaning that if I have to map the `sourceObj` to `destObj` for second time using a new ModelMapper instance, that it will have to re-create the `TypeMap`.

I'm assuming this is a fairly expensive operation, say if I'm mapping a collection of `sourceObj` to `destObj`. This leads me to the conclusion that I should re-use the ModelMapper instance.

Is this conclusion correct?

thanks

Answer (score 9):

Yes. There is even a section in the [FAQ](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/faq/) about this:

> Should I reuse my ModelMapper instance?
>
> Unless you need different mappings between the same types, then it’s best to re-use the same ModelMapper instance. If you use a dependency injection container, you can accomplish this by configuring ModelMapper as a singleton.

Comment: Thanks! Somehow missed that section.